# jQuery event scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery

`#mydiv` is a clickable box Div,a class `.openDiv` will be added if click on `#mydiv`.

if has class `.openDiv`

```
if($('#mydiv').hasClass('openDiv')){
 $(window).scrollTop(); //value is 300px
}
```

if just the page loaded (no `.openDiv` )

```
$(window).scrollTop(); //value is 200px
```

so my variable is like

```
if($('#mydiv').hasClass('openDiv')){
  thisTop =  $(window).scrollTop() - 100;
}else{
  thisTop =  $(window).scrollTop() 
}
```

as you can see I made it `100` different value hard coded. Is there a way to make it to calculate dynamically?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var div = $('#mydiv'), scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
thisTop = div.hasClass('openDiv') ? scrollTop - div.height() : scrollTop;
```

If `#mydiv` has the class `openDiv` then take away it's height from `$(window).scrollTop()`, otherwise just return `$(window).scrollTop()`.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you can find the height of every object using the .height() method. I don't know where does the 100px come form but you can replace it by $('InsertASelectorHere').height()